# Sumar por grupos en Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Con un df como este:

```
    fid DISTRITO UBIGEO  Area_km2
  <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1     1 GUZMANGO  60504    0.0630
2     2 GUZMANGO  60504    0.0170
3    42 EL PRADO  61105    0.173 
4    43 EL PRADO  61105    0.0689
5    44 EL PRADO  61105    0.0705
```

Con dplyr (en R) puedo calcular el área total de cada distrito y tenerla como una columna con el siguiente código:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
  group_by(DISTRITO) %>%
  mutate(TotAreaUrb=sum(Area_km2))
```

Obteniendo esto:

```
    fid DISTRITO UBIGEO  Area_km2 TotAreaUrb
  <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>
1     1 GUZMANGO  60504    0.0630     0.0800
2     2 GUZMANGO  60504    0.0170     0.0800
3    42 EL PRADO  61105    0.173      0.312 
4    43 EL PRADO  61105    0.0689     0.312 
5    44 EL PRADO  61105    0.0705     0.312
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer lo mismo con pandas en Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En R y en Python aunque la sintaxis sea ligeramente distinta, las librerías suelen tener la misma lógica, por lo que no es difícil resolver un mismo problema en ambos lenguajes, o encontrar soluciones.

Copiando tu problema, se resolvería así:

```
import pandas as pd

df_distritos = pd.DataFrame({"DISTRITO":["GUZMANGO", "GUZMANGO", "EL PRADO", 
                                         "EL PRADO", "EL PRADO"],
                             "Area_km2": [0.0630, 0.0170, 0.173, 0.0689, 0.0705]})

df_distritos["TotAreaUrb"]= df_distritos.groupby("DISTRITO").transform("sum")
```

**Salida:**

```
    DISTRITO    Area_km2    TotAreaUrb
0   GUZMANGO    0.0630  0.0800
1   GUZMANGO    0.0170  0.0800
2   EL PRADO    0.1730  0.3124
3   EL PRADO    0.0689  0.3124
4   EL PRADO    0.0705  0.3124
```

El proceso es el siguiente:

1. Agrupamos las columnas con el método `groupby`.
2. Después usamos el método `transform` que nos mantiene los indices y la posición para cualquier operación que vayamos a usar
3. Le indicamos que la operación a usar es la suma `.transform("sum")`

Para saber más sobre `Pandas` te recomiendo utilizar su [documentación oficial](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/), es sencilla e incluso tiene tutoriales que puedes seguir.

Comment: Con la solución que planteas se pierden el resto de columnas y las filas se reducen a una sola. Lo que busco, como planteo en el ejemplo de la pregunta, es agregar una columna que repita la suma en tantas filas como existan por distrito. Es decir, si el distrito 'EL PRADO' tuviera 7 filas, cada una con un 'Area_km2' distinta, la columna 'TotAreaUrb' debería repetir 7 veces la suma de estas. ¿Es posible?

Comment: He editado la respuesta! Espero que te sirva

Comment: Gracias! En efecto, me sirvió bastante :)

Comment: De nada siempre es un gusto ayudar :) Si te ha servido mis respuesta, la mejor forma de dar las gracias en StackOverflow es aceptando la respuesta en el tick  "aceptar respuesta",  y ¿Por qué no? ¡Darle también un voto positivo! Esto no solo me recomenpensara a mí por la ayuda, si no que hará que la pregunta perdure en el tiempo y le pueda ser de ayuda a personas con el mismo problema que tú en el futuro! Te recomiendo leer [Vota pronto, vota con frecuencia](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2209/vota-pronto-vota-con-frecuencia)